# Pretty not reWrite URL in new window

Tags: jsf, primefaces, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

I am using Primefaces 5.1 with JSF and PrettyFaces.In commandlink to press open page in new window at the page open new window fine but the rewrite URL is not working.

**Javascript**

```
    var newwin=null;

     function NewWindow(mypage,myname)
    {
        params  = 'width='+screen.width;
        params += ', height='+screen.height;
        params += ', top=0, left=0';
        //params +=', scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes';
        params +=', scrollbars=yes';
        newwin=window.open(mypage,myname, params);
        if (window.focus)
        {
            newwin.focus()
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Xhmtl**

```
<p:commandLink value="Link" ajax="false" onclick="return 
    NewWindow('#{request.contextPath}/pages/student/userMain.xhtml','user');"/>
```

**prettyConfig.xml**

```
<url-mapping id="user">
    <pattern value="/user" />
    <view-id value="/faces/pages/student/userMain.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

My doubt is in same window URL reWrite is works fine but in new window not working it show given full path then how reWrite URL in new window.In above code to need any other changes  to reWrite how to show in new Window.

Comment: When you debug your JS, are your window parameters correct? '(mypage,myname,params)'

Comment: @WitYoBadSelf Yes it's correct